# Is it possible to create a GUI with Apache Spark, and Pyspark

Tags: user-interface, apache-spark, pyspark, urwid

Two weeks ago, i started messing around with Apache spark, scala, and pyspark. I downloaded the hortonworks operating system, and was playing around with it.

I developed a little application, and will like to demo it to my friends, but i will like to have a FrontEnd/GUI. It will most likely be just one page, just to display the functionalities of what i am doing.

I know python has a console user interface called URWID. Is it possible to integrate this with PYSPARK, if not, what are my other choices?

Comment: Have you heard of notebooks, such as [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) and [Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/)?  They provide a web UI for writing, running, and displaying the results of Spark jobs (among other things).  You may not be interested in web UIs, but they're very convenient for hands-on demonstrations.  I think Jupyter is written in Python and probably has a stronger Python ecosystem than Zeppelin.

Comment: @DavidKaczynski Thanks, i have used jupyter, and i use it still, just wondering how easy it will be to integrate it with hortonworks sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

**Try Apache Livy**

Livy enables programmatic, fault-tolerant, multi-tenant submission of Spark jobs from web/mobile apps (no Spark client needed). So, multiple users can interact with your Spark cluster concurrently and reliably.

[Click here for Apache Livy docs](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/)